# justify Arabic text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, arabic, text-alignment, arabic-support, text-justify

I want to justify Arabic text In my App but using TextAlign.justify leaves large spaces between words! Is there a better way to align words in flutter reducing those spaces knowing that Arabic words can be extended like this "الناس" to "النــــــاس" by adding "ــ" between letters in the word.
Thanks

[image]